# day-month-year from the daytime date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am running

```
select distinct day(rectime) from dbo.tbl_testrecord
```

to get distinct day for rectime . now i want distinct month and day from the rectime for example sep 10.
how to do that?
Please advice!

Answer (score 0):

Use `datepart`

```
select distinct
  cast(datename(month,datepart(mm,rectime) as varchar(10))) 
+ cast(datepart(dd,rectime) as varchar(10))
+ ','  
+ cast(datepart(yyyy,rectime) as varchar(10))
from dbo.tbl_testrecord
```

Comment: its giving me like 20150910 format, i am looking something like Sep 10 ,2015

Comment: see the modified version

Answer (score 0):

If you want to truncate the time from a date you can `CAST` `DATETIME` to `DATE`

```
select distinct cast(rectime as date) from dbo.tbl_testrecord
```

If you want the date parts as individual columns then

```
select distinct 
    day(rectime) as d, month(rectime) as m, year(rectime) as y 
from dbo.tbl_testrecord
```

Comment: for first script i am getting error like Type date is not a defined system type. (I am using sql server 2008). But second will helpful. thanks

Comment: I am pretty certain [`DATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) is available in SQL Server 2008, what is the [Compatibility Level](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933794%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) of the database?